# Next.js using SWR with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js, swr

I'm trying to use SWR to prefetch data in my project.
Here is my code:

```js
export const getStaticProps = async (res) => {
  const result = await axios.get(
    `/orders/detail/${res.params.cid}/${res.params.oid}`
  );
  const orderDetailById = await result.data;

  return {
    props: { orderDetailById },
  };
};

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const result = await fetch(`${server}/api/orders`);

  const orders = await result.json();

  const ids = orders.map((order_detail) => ({
    oid: order_detail.oid,
    cid: order_detail.cid,
  }));
  const paths = ids.map((id) => ({
    params: { oid: id.oid.toString(), cid: id.cid.toString() },
  }));
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
};

const fetcher = (url, params) => {
  return fetch(url + params.cid + '/' + params.oid).then((r) => r.json());
};

const OrderDetailByOId = ({ orderDetailById }) => {
  const cid = orderDetailById.customer[0].cid;
  const oid = orderDetailById.detail[0].oid;

  const params = useMemo(() => ({ cid, oid }), [cid, oid]);

  const { data, error } = useSWR(['/orders/detail/', params], fetcher, {
    initialData: orderDetailById,
  });

  if (error) {
    console.log('errorHere', error);
    return <div>failed to load</div>;
  }
  if (!data) return <div>Loading...</div>;
  return <OrderDetailForm orderDetailById={orderDetailById} />;
};

export default OrderDetailByOId;
```

It works well in the first render.
At the same time, I didn't change any data in my database,
so when it renders the second time by `refreshInterval:1000` it wouldn't change anything, but it popped up with some errors!

`errorHere SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

When I first saw the error I guessed it was just some JSON problems, so I changed the fetcher's return like `(r)=>r.data`

After I changed this, it caused the web to return `loading...`
It means it didn't fetch anything in the second render or even each after the first render.

Did anyone can help me find out what problems caused the errors.
Thanks~

Comment: Is the request inside the `fetcher` pointing to the right URL? Shouldn't the `useSWR` key be `/api/orders/detail/`?

Comment: @juliomalves Thank you to pointing me out!!!~ I forgot I have written this `Axios.defaults.baseURL = server + '/api';` in `_app.js`. So I changed it to axios.get() and return `r.data` back, it works fine now~~ Will you like to answer down below, and I'll give you the green check~

Answer (score 0):

I forgot I have set Axios basic URl like `Axios.defaults.baseURL = server + '/api';`

so I changed the fetcher return like   `return axios.get(url + params.cid + '/' + params.oid).then((r) => r.data);`

It works for me now~ Thanks for the @juliomalves pointing me out where could be a problem ~ Thanks!